# Hi Everyone..I need help for resolve my problem about integrating interstitial ads onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, admob

The problem: I experienced was when pressing the ad button, the application suddenly closed immediately after the ad appears. 
what I want when I press the ad button is the ad appears then when the ad is closed, it will return to the previous activity.

Thank you very much. this code that I made:

```
private ImageView mBackgroundImage;    
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        interstitialAd.show();
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                finish();
            }
        });
        if (PopupManager.isShown()) {
            PopupManager.closePopup();
            if (ScreenController.getLastScreen() == ScreenController.Screen.GAME) {
                Shared.eventBus.notify(new BackGameEvent());
            }
        } else if (ScreenController.getInstance().onBack()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy () {
        Shared.engine.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: javascript != java. Please use proper tags.

Comment: Look at your onBackPressed() again. Most probably the condition PopupManager.isShown() is evaluated to false and hence the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your Idea @RahulShukla, i will try to find out